# Customize target folder in grails run-app

Tags: grails

Is there a way to define a custom Target folder while running the grails application along with other params?

`grails -D'Target folder' run-app`

Comment: What do you mean by customize target folder. You want to change it's name or something?

Comment: yes i want to specify the custom location